# Two different Sharepoint 2010 Designer workflows for Email Remider

Tags: designer-workflow

My requirement is to run the SPD 2010 workflow on daily basis and check the days for item expiration and depends on that days send Email reminder to user.

To achieve this I have implemented 2 different workflows referring below link:
http://www.attunix.com/sharepoint-2010-daily-reminder-loop/

I have run this on 10 min interval and it was working fine but after running for several time it stop working and status for both the workflow is completed without any error.

For some items its runs for ~455 times and for another item ~250 times and then stop working.
when look into the workflow i found the secondary workflow not able to trigger the Primary one.

**But after running successfully for near about more than 250 times is there any reason to Stopped the working of the workflow ???**

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your environment or error logs, but I have a work around.  Use Information Management Policy to watch for the expiration date.  Have it trigger a workflow that sends out the email.

[Like this](https://blog.splibrarian.com/2013/03/27/setting-up-automated-reminder-emails/)

Comment: This is the correct answer.